# SwiftでFirebase Cloud Messagingを用いてデバイス間でプッシュ通知を送信したい

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification

Firebase Authを利用してログインし、ユーザーが任意のグループに参加すると、1人がアプリ上のボタンを押したタイミングでグループ内の他のユーザーへプッシュ通知が届くというiOSアプリを制作しています。

[デバイス間でPush通知を送り合う with SwiftUI, Firebase Cloud Messaging | Zenn](https://zenn.dev/aphananthe42/articles/132a2d823bd0a3)
こちらの記事を参考に、それぞれのデバイスのトークンを取得してFirestoreへ保存し、HTTPリクエストを行う部分まで来たのですが、サーバーキーは2024年1月現在すでに取得できず、HTTP v1へ移行していることが分かりました。代わりにOAuth 2.0アクセストークンを取得すれば良いというところまでは調べてわかったのですが、公式ドキュメントにはSwiftでの取得方法の記載はなく、どのようにすれば良いのか分かりません。

通知送信部分のコードは下記の通りです。

Firebaseドキュメントの「[以前の HTTP から HTTP v1 に移行する  |  Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=ja)」を参照しながら、HTTP v1に対応するように一部変更しました。

```
 func send(token: String, userId: String, title: String, body: String){

　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　//ここが欲しい
        let accessToken = <OAuth2.0_ACCESS_TOKEN>
        
        let endpoint = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/messages:send"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else { return }
        let paramString: [String: Any] = ["message": ["token": token, "notification": ["title": title, "body": body]],
                                                "data": ["userId": userId]]
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, _ in
                    do {
                        if let jsonData = data {
                            if let jsonDataDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                print("Received data: \(jsonDataDict)")
                            }
                        }
                    } catch let err as NSError {
                        print(err.debugDescription)
                    }
                }
        task.resume()
        
    }
```

この関数をButtonタップ時に実行しています。

今まではFirebaseのダッシュボードで確認できるサーバーキーさえ分かればよかったのだと思いますが、HTTP v1 APIに対応した方法がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

一応自己解決しました。

FirebaseAuthだけではOAuth2.0アクセストークンを取得する方法は分からなかったので、GoogleSignIn-iOSライブラリを導入してGoogle認証を行い、

[iOS アプリで Google API にアクセスする Google for Developers](https://iOS%20%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A7%20Google%20API%20%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

を参考にしながら、スコープ `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging`
をリクエストした後に

```
refreshTokensIfNeededWithCompletion
```

を呼び出すことで、無事OAuth2.0アクセストークンを取得することができ、プッシュ通知をデバイス間で送信することができました。

ただこの方法では問題が山積みで

1. FirebaseAuthとGoogleSignInの二つでログインしているため、ログイン時は1回で済むが、ログアウト時は両方ともログアウト処理をする必要があり、どちらか片方だけがログインしている状況にならないか心配。Cloud Firestoreを利用しているため、GoogleSignInに一本化することもできない。
2. 本来アプリにはTwitterやAppleでのサインインも導入したかったが、上記の方法でできるのはGoogleサインインのみであるため、ログイン方法が一つに限られてしまった。（TwitterによるログインでもGoogleサービスのスコープをリクエストしてOAuth2.0アクセストークンを取得できるのかは試していないので不明。もしできたとしてもログインプロバイダの数だけ処理を記述する必要がある）
3. GoogleSignIn-iOSではすでにログイン済みのアカウントに対してスコープのリクエストを行うため、初回のFirebaseAuthのログイン時にスコープをリクエストできず、必ず2回ログイン画面を開く必要がある。

などの様々な問題があり、セキュリティが低いとはいえ、以前までのサーバーキーで送信できるシステムの方がユーザーのログイン自体も不要で圧倒的に楽だったんだなと思いました。

他にもGoogle APIのIAM Permissionの扱いがよく分からず、現状では利用者のGoogleアカウントを一つ一つ手動で許可リストに加えていかないと、権限エラーで通知が送信できないという問題もあるので、別で質問させていただこうと思います。